# Estou com erro ao atribuir um estilo a uma tag por meio do js

Tags: javascript, html, dev-tools

//Folha do HTML

````
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Projeto 1.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Apostas <span style="color: #F9DD16;">Futebolisticas</span></h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        <section id="firstQuest">
            <div id="Quest">
                <h2>Quantas jogos irá analizar ?</h2>
                <select id="QuantJogos">
                    <option value="5">5 Jogos</option>
                    <option value="10">10 Jogos</option>
                    <option value="15">15 Jogos</option>
                    <option value="20">20 Jogos</option>
                    <option value="25">25 Jogos</option>
                    <option value="30">30 Jogos</option>
                    <option value="35">35 Jogos</option>
                    <option value="40">40 Jogos</option>
                    <option value="45">45 Jogos</option>
                    <option value="50">50 Jogos</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn" onclick="confirmar()">Confirmar</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="ft1" class="ajust">
            <div class="BackDoor">
                <h2>Média de Gols</h2>
                <div class="filler">
                    <p>Aguardando entrada de quantos jogos irá analizar</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="ft2" class="ajust">
            <div class="BackDoor">
                <h2>Média de Escanteios</h2>
                <div class="filler">
                    <p>Aguardando entrada de quantos jogos irá analizar</p>
                </div>
                <div class="conteudo">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="ft3" class="ajust">
            <div class="BackDoor">
                <h2>Média de Cartões</h2>
                <div class="filler">
                    <p>Aguardando entrada de quantos jogos irá analizar</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>

</html>```

//Folha do js

```function confirmar(){
    let jogos = document.getElementById("QuantJogos")
    let numJogos = Number(jogos.value)
    clear()
    adicionar()
}

function clear(){
    let i = 0
    while(i<=3){
        let msg = document.getElementsByClassName("filler")[i]
        msg.style.display="none"
        i++
    }
}

function adicionar(){
    let div = document.getElementsByClassName("conteudo")[0]
    div.style.display = "block"
    div.innerHTML="<p><input type='button' id='Botao' value='Confirmar'></p>"
} ```

O erro que está dando: "index.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')"
````

Answer (score 1):

Há algumas formas de fazer isso.

Primeiro ponto é entender a diferença de getElementsByClassName e getElementById.
O primeiro gera um array, o segundo um unico elemento.
Inclusive, percebi que sé tem um elemento com classe conteudo, vc poderia o chamar com querySelector('.conteudo');
E também quando quiser mais de um elemento pode chamar com querySelectorAll('.classe') que gera um array.

Cria a variável pegando os elementos do "filler" global, fora das funções. Sem passar o index.

Na função faz o for MAS, especifique que ele vai ate que i seja MENOR que o length dessa variavel.
Ai vc chama essa variavel[i]
O que acontece, se vc so tiver 3 elementos, vai ter posicao 0,1 e 2
E ali vc disse enquanto i for <= ou seja, inclusive 3 (que nao existe, logo, dando erro pq nao da pra atribuir style em um undefined.)

E fazendo o for e setando que será enquanto i for MENOR que o length do objeto, você não terá esse problema pois, quando acabar os indices você não tentará atribuir um style ao que não existe.

Lembrando: Javascript se encontrar um erro, encerra tudo e não só aquele método que está.

Answer (score -3):

Observando o que você disse, é só você por o estilo pelo css, ai vc consegue fazer isso que vc queria, ou no pior dos casos não por o estilo

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).